# What is the recommended level for each published adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, character-levels

I thought I would ask a different take on a question that seems to be asked often here (I need an adventure for level x)

What I am looking for is a list of official sources and the recommended level(s) to play through the adventure. I understand there are ways to make things more difficult for more experienced/higher level players but I was hoping to find a nice list of adventures with the recommended playing levels for playing as-is.

Hopefully this will stop me having to keep googling "which adventures are best for a level x party" and getting the same answers for different levels!

Comment: I've cast a vote to leave this question open. It's possible to read the question as a request for a list (rather than a link to a list), which would be on-topic, a good RPG.SE question, and not a "shopping" request. This is also how @Nobody the Hobgoblin has answered the question, and it's a useful answer.

Comment: @Kerrick I think a list request is on topic, but as it stands that isn't what has been asked for. I hope it gets edited rather than closed though, because this could remain a great resource if the community keeps it updated.

Comment: @SeriousBri I’ve only slightly modified this question to be an adequately scoped and objective list sort of question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: My apologies everyone that responded and answered this. I ended up having things to attend to shortly after posting this and didn't get time to come back round to it. Thank you @ThomasMarkov for the edit, I would have done it myself had I seen this earlier.

Comment: @Kerrick Thank you for the re-open vote. If I had been told it was off topic and why originally I'd have happily edited the question. Unfortunately wasn't able to get there in time, but glad the community decided to re-open it!

Comment: I hope the downvoters reconsider the votes now the question is edited and answered. Please consider leaving a comment along with a downvote so I can address the issue and improve the question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a list of the published adventures by Wizards of the Coast, spanning from well known "official" hardcover modules to more obscure content like charity PDFs and Adventurer's League modules.

#### Hardcovers & Boxed Sets

Wikipedia provides a [list of the official 5e modules and boxed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_adventures), along with modules for other editions of the game. The list gives you the level ranges for each of them in the last column.

| Title | Levels |
| --- | --- |
| **Module** |  |
| The Lost Mine of Phandelver (revamped as Phandelver and Below: The Shattered Obelisk, see below) | 1-5 |
| Hoard of the Dragon Queen | 1-8 |
| The Rise of Tiamat | 8-15 |
| Princes of the Apocalypse | 1-15 |
| Out of the Abyss | 1-15 |
| Curse of Strahd | 1-10 |
| Storm King's Thunder | 1-11 |
| Tomb of Annihilation | 1-9+ |
| Waterdeep: Dragon Heist | 1-5 |
| Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage | 5-20 |
| Baldur's Gate: Descent Into Avernus | 1-13 |
| Tyranny of Dragons (includes Hoard of the Dragon Queen and The Rise of Tiamat) | 1-15 |
| Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden | 1-12 |
| The Wild Beyond the Witchlight | 1-8 |
| Critical Role: Call of the Netherdeep | 3-12 |
| Dragonlance: Shadow of the Dragon Queen | 1-11 |
| Phandelver and Below: The Shattered Obelisk | 1-12 |
| **Anthology** |  |
| Tales from the Yawning Portal (includes 7 adventures) | 1-11+ [1-3, 3-5, 5-8, 8-9, 9-11, 11-14, 10-14] |
| Ghosts of Saltmarsh (includes 7 adventures) | 1-12 [1-2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11] |
| Candlekeep Mysteries (includes 17 adventures) | 1-16 (one for each level 1-16, and an extra one for level 4) |
| Journeys through the Radiant Citadel (includes 13 adventures) | 1-14 (one for level 1-2, and one more for each level from 2 to 14) |
| Keys From the Golden Vault (includes 13 adventures) | 1-11 (one for each level, with an extra one for each level 5 and 8) |
| **Boxed/Starter Set** |  |
| Stranger Things Dungeons & Dragons Starter Set | 3-4 |
| Dungeons & Dragons Essentials Kit | 1-6 |
| Dungeons & Dragons vs. Rick and Morty | 1-3 |
| Curse of Strahd: Revamped | 1–10 |
| Spelljammer: Adventures in Space | 5-8 |
| Starter Set: Dragons of Stormwreck Isle | 1–3 |
| Planescape: Adventures in the Multiverse | 3-10, 17 |

Most campaign books start at level 1, and most will take you up all the way to level 10 to 15, so there is no need to find different adventures at each given level. Among these, *Hoard of the Dragon Queen / Rise of Tiamat* and the two *Waterdeep:* modules are designed to be played in sequence.

If you however prefer to string together a campaign from standalone short adventures, of particular interest may be the Anthologies, which contain shorter unrelated, or loosely related adventures across a range of the levels. The list is not that long, so it should not be so hard to quickly scan it to see which one supports play for a level you have in mind.

#### Charity Modules and Crossovers

There are also a number of extras that have been published for charity events or from popular live-streaming shows, like *The Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*, or *Dungeons of Drakkenheim* (level 1-13). I've not inculuded all of those, but you can find a list of them [on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/adventures).

There are more adventures offered on [DM's Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com/browse/pub/44/Wizards-of-the-Coast) by Wizards of the Coast. It is a bit unclear which of them one would count as "official", for example the highly rated *Chains of Asmodeus* is offered by Wizards of the Coast but is not using the Dungeons & Dragons name, it just says "Fifth Edition".

| Title | Levels |
| --- | --- |
| The Tortle Package | 1–4 |
| The Lost Kenku | 4 |
| X Marks the Spot | 4 |
| Lost Laboratory of Kwalish | 5–10 |
| Krenko's Way | 1–2 |
| A Zib for Your Thoughts | 2 |
| Hunt for the Thessalhydra | 3–4 |
| Locathah Rising | 9 |
| Infernal Machine Rebuild | 5–10 |
| The Lost Dungeon of Rickedness: Big Rick Energy | 1–3 |
| Eberron: Rising from the Last War: Forgotten Relics | 1 |
| Wildemount: Tide of Retribution | 1–3 |
| Wildemount: Dangerous Designs | 1–3 |
| Wildemount: Frozen Sick | 1–3 |
| Wildemount: Unwelcome Spirits | 1–3 |
| Return to the Glory | 6–8 |
| Adventures in the Forgotten Realms: In Scarlet Flames | 8 |
| Adventures in the Forgotten Realms: The Hidden Page | 8–9 |
| Adventures in the Forgotten Realms: A Verdant Tomb | 9 |
| Adventures in the Forgotten Realms: Deepest Night | 9–10 |
| Adventures in the Forgotten Realms: From Cyan Depths | 10 |
| NERDS Restoring Harmony: The Candy Mountain Caper | 1–3 |
| NERDS Restoring Harmony: A Voice in the Wilderness | 1–3 |
| NERDS Restoring Harmony: A Sticky Situation | 1–3 |
| NERDS Restoring Harmony: Circus of Illusion | 1–3 |
| NERDS Restoring Harmony: The Lost Tomb | 1–3 |
| NERDS Restoring Harmony: A Web of Lies | 1–3 |
| NERDS Restoring Harmony: Adventure Together | 1–3 |
| Spelljammer Academy | 1–4 |
| Giants of the Star Forge | 16 |
| Lightning Keep | 3 |
| Chains of Asmodeus | 11–20 |
| Peril in Pinebrook | 1 |
| Heroes' Feast: Saving the Childrens Menu | 10 |

#### Adventurer's League Modules

Also official were the D&D Expeditions and Adventurer's League modules that originally matched the most recent hardcover adventure published (data courtesy of [Forgotten Realms Fandom Wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Adventurers_League), who also have more detail on the adventures).

| Season 1 - Tyranny of Dragons | Levels Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDEX1-01 - Defiance in Phlan | 1st – 2nd |
| DDEX1-02 - Secrets of Sokol Keep | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX1-03 - Shadows over the Moonsea | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX1-04 - Dues for the Dead | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX1-05 - The Courting of Fire | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX1-06 - The Scroll Thief | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX1-07 - Drums in the Marsh | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX1-08 - Tales Trees Tell | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX1-09 - Outlaws of the Iron Route | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX1-10 - Tyranny in Phlan | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX1-11 - Dark Pyramid of Sorcerer's Isle | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX1-12 - Raiders of the Twilight Marsh | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX1-13 - Pool of Radiance Resurgent | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX1-14 - Escape from Phlan | 5th – 10th |
| DDEP1-1 - Corruption in Kryptgarden | 1st – 5th |

| Season 2 - Elemental Evil | Levels Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDEX2-01 - City of Danger | 1st – 2nd |
| DDEX2-02 - Embers of Elmwood | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX2-03 - The Drowned Tower | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX2-04 - Mayhem in the Earthspur Mines | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX2-05 - Flames of Kythorn | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX2-06 - Breath of the Yellow Rose | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX2-07 - Bounty in the Bog | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX2-08 - Foulness Beneath Mulmaster | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX2-09 - Eye of the Tempest | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX2-10 - Cloaks and Shadows | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX2-11 - Oubliette of Fort Iron | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX2-12 - Dark Rites at Fort Dalton | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX2-13 - The Howling Void | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX2-14 - The Sword of Selfaril | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX2-15 - Black Heart of Vengeance | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX2-16 - Boltsmelter's Book | 1st – 4th |
| DDEP2-1 - Mulmaster Undone | 1st – 10th |

| Season 3 - Rage of Demons | Levels Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDEX3-01 - Harried in Hillsfar | 1st – 2nd |
| DDEX3-02 - Shackles of Blood | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX3-03 - The Occupation of Szith Morcane | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX3-04 - It's All in the Blood | 11th – 16th |
| DDEX3-05 - Bane of the Tradeways | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX3-06 - No Foolish Matter | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX3-07 - Herald of the Moon | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX3-08 - The Malady of Elventree | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX3-09 - The Waydown | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX3-10 - Quelling the Horde | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX3-11 - The Quest for Sporedome | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX3-12 - Hillsfar Reclaimed | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX3-13 - Writhing in the Dark | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX3-14 - Death on the Wall | 1st – 4th |
| DDEX3-15 - Szith Morcane Unbound | 5th – 10th |
| DDEX3-16 - Assault on Maerimydra | 11th – 16th |
| DDEP3 - Blood Above, Blood Below | 1st – 16th |

| Season 4 - Curse of Strahd | Levels Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDAL4-01 - Suits of the Mists | 1st – 2nd |
| DDAL4-02 - The Beast | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL4-03 - The Executioner | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL4-04 - The Marionette | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL4-05 - The Seer | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL4-06 - The Ghost | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL4-07 - The Innocent | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL4-08 - The Broken One | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL4-09 - The Tempter | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL4-10 - The Artifact | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL4-11 - The Donjon | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL4-12 - The Raven | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL4-13 - The Horseman | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL4-14 - The Darklord | 5th – 10th |
| DDEP4 - Reclamation of Phlan | 1st – 16th |

| Season 5 - Storm King's Thunder | Levels Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDAL5-01 - Treasure of the Broken Hoard | 1st – 2nd |
| DDAL5-02 - The Black Road | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL5-03 - Uninvited Guests | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL5-04 - In Dire Need | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL5-05 - A Dish Best Served Cold | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL5-06 - Beneath the Fetid Chelimber | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL5-07 - Chelimber's Descent | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL5-08 - Durlag's Tower | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL5-09 - Durlag's Tomb | 11th – 16th |

| Season 6 - Tales From the Yawning Portal | Levels Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDAL6-01 - A Thousand Tiny Deaths | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL6-02 - The Redemption of Kelvan | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL6-03 - Crypt of the Death Giants | 17th – 20th |
| DDEP6-01 - Relics of Khundrukar | 1st – 10th |
| DDEP6-02 - Return to White Plume Mountain | 1st – 10th |
| DDEP6-03 - Hecatomb | 11th – 20th |
| DDIA06 - The Sunless Citadel | 1st – 4th |

| Season 7 - Tomb of Annihilation | Levels Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDAL07-01 - A City on the Edge | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL07-02 - Over the Edge | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL07-03 - A Day at the Races | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL07-04 - A Walk in the Park | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL07-05 - Whispers in the Dark | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL07-06 - Fester and Burn | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL07-07 - Rotting Roots | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL07-08 - Putting the Dead to Rest | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL07-09 - Unusual Opposition | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL07-10 - Fire, Ash, and Ruin | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL07-11 - A Lesson in Love | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL07-12 - In Search of Secrets | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL07-13 - Old Bones and Older Tomes | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL07-14 - Fathomless Pits of Ill Intent | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL07-15 - Streams of Crimson | 17th – 20th |
| DDAL07-16 - Pools of Cerulean | 17th – 20th |
| DDAL07-17 - Cauldron of Sapphire | 17th – 20th |
| DDAL07-18 - Turn Back the Endless Night | 17th – 20th |
| DDEP07-01 - Peril at the Port | 1st – 10th |
| DDEP07-02 - Drums of the Dead | 1st – 20th |

| Season 8 - Waterdeep | Levels Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDAL08-00 - Once in Waterdeep | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL08-01 - The Map with No Names | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL08-02 - Beneath the City of the Dead | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL08-03 - Dock Ward Double-Cross | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL08-04 - A Wrinkle in the Weave | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL08-05 - Hero of the Troll Wars | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL08-06 - Purging the Blood | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL08-07 - Into the Dark | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL08-08 - Crypt of the Dark Kiss | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL08-09 - Fangs and Frogs | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL08-10 - The Skull Square Murders | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL08-11 - Poisoned Words | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL08-12 - Xanathar's Wrath | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL08-13 - The Vampire of Skullport | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL08-14 - Rescue from Vanrakdoom | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL08-15 - Forge of Fangs | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL08-16 - A Change of Address | 17th – 20th |
| DDAL08-17 - The Tower of Ahghairon | 17th – 20th |
| DDAL08-18 - Moving Day | 17th – 20th |
| DDEP08-01 - Chaos in the City of Splendors | 1st – 4th |
| DDEP08-02 - Stardock Under Siege | 1st – 16th |
| DDEP08-03 - Last Orders at the Yawning Portal | 1st – 20th |

| Season 9 - Avernus Rising | Level Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDAL09-01 - Escape from Elturgard | 1st – 2nd |
| DDAL09-02 - Stopped at the Gate | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL09-03 - Hungry Shadows | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL09-04 - Day of the Devil | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL09-05 - Faces of Fortune | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL09-06 - Infernal Insurgency | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL09-07 - The Diabolical Dive | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL09-08 - In the Garden of Evil | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL09-09 - Ruined Prospects | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL09-10 - Tipping the Scales | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL09-11 - Losing Fai | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL09-12 - The Breath of Life | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL09-13 - The Swarmed Heart | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL09-14 - The Vast Emptiness of Grace | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL09-15 - Maddening Screams | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL09-16 - Honors Unforeseen | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL09-17 - In the Hand | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL09-18 - Consequences of Choice | 11th – 16th |
| DDAL09-19 - Fang and Claw | 17th – 20th |
| DDAL09-20 - Where Devils Fear to Tread | 17th – 20th |
| DDEP09-01 - Infernal Pursuits | 1st – 10th |
| DDEP09-02 - Hellfire Requiem | 1st – 4th |
| DDEP09-03 - Liar's Night | 1st – 4th |

| Season 10 - Plague of Ancients | Level Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDAL10-00 - Ice Road Trackers | 1st – 2nd |
| DDAL10-01 - The Frozen North | 1st – 2nd |
| DDAL10-02 - Gnashing Teeth | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL10-03 - Divining Evil | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL10-04 - Cold Benevolence | 1st – 4th |
| DDAL10-05 - A Blight in the Darkness | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL10-06 - The Fallen Star | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL10-07 - Into Darkness | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL10-08 - Volatile Thoughts | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL10-09 - Recipe for Retribution | 5th – 10th |
| DDAL10-10 - Burying the Past | 10th – 13th |
| DDEP10-00 - The Great Knucklehead Rally | 1st – 4th |
| DDEP10-01 - Terror in Ten Towns | 1st – 4th |
| DDEP10-02 - Song of Spears | 5th – 13th |

| Dreams of the Red Wizards | Level Range |
| --- | --- |
| DDAL-DRW01 - Breaking Umberlee's Resolve | 5th - 10th |
| DDAL-DRW02 - Blood in the Water | 5th - 10th |
| DDAL-DRW03 - Saving Silverbeard | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW04 - Foreign Affairs | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW05 - Uncertain Scrutiny | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW06 - Thimblerigging | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW07 - Moment of Peace | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW08 - The Harrowing of Hell | 17th - 20th |
| DDAL-DRW09 - Vile Bounty | 5th - 10th |
| DDAL-DRW10 - Unsafe Harborage | 5th - 10th |
| DDAL-DRW11 - Shadows in the Stacks | 5th - 10th |
| DDAL-DRW12 - To Walk the Cold Dark | 5th - 10th |
| DDAL-DRW13 - Night Thieves | 5th - 10th |
| DDAL-DRW14 - The City That Should Not Be | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW15 - Frozen Whispers | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW16 - Uprising | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW17 - Expedition to the Supreme Forge | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW18 - Against the Machine | 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW19 - Fall the Cold Night | 17th - 20th |
| DDAL-DRW20 - The Death of Szass Tam | 17th - 20th |
| DDAL-DRW-INT-01 - Big Problems | 1st - 4th |
| DDAL-DRW-INT-02 - Watchers of the Trollclaws | 1st - 4th |
| DDAL-DRW-INT-03 - A Red Day for Elventree | 1st - 4th |
| DDAL-DRW-INT-04 - Tales of Fang and Claw | 1st - 4th |
| DDEP-DRW01 - Assault on Myth Nantar | 5th - 16th |
| DDEP-DRW02 - Wings of Death | 11th - 20th |
| DDAL-DRW-EP-03 - When the Lights Went Out in Candlekeep | 5th - 10th & 11th - 16th |
| DDAL-DRW-EP-04 - Tears Among the Stars | 11th - 16th & 17th - 20th |

Thanks to @nitsua60 and @Kerrik for pointing out sources to help complete this list.

Comment: This is an absolutely fantastic answer and just what I was wanting. My apologies for not responding earlier (or editing the question to make it more on topic. I had some urgent things to attend to shortly after posting), but this was the answer I was looking for. Not sure how my Google skills were so bad I couldn't find the Wikipedia page though!

Comment: The addition of Adventurer's League content really elevates this answer.  Good job!

Comment: Somehow "Hardcovers & Boxed Sets" looks like a title though, whereas the actual answer encompasses much more.

Comment: @Jack Thanks you are right I wondered about it too. I added a small intro paragraph to dispel that impression.

Comment: @nitsua60, V2Blast  I added Forgotten Relics to the list, thank you for digging it up.

Comment: Why does this have 2 downvotes?